# Readelf finding absolute address

Tags: linker, readelf

I have a C programme which has one global and one local variable. My question is on the readelf. Following are my questions;
1. When i take the address dump using "readelf --symbols", i get an address for my global variable which is same as that of the address i print when i run the programme. How the readelf can know the absolute address before my programme is running or been loaded?
2. Why there are no informations on the local variables' symbols?. I can see only global variables' symbols.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How readelf can know the absolute address before my programme is running or been loaded?

Because by the time the linker has done its work, the address computed for
your global variable *is* the address at which the program loader will
have to place that variable at runtime. The job of the linker is largely to
put information into an executable that tells the program loader where
symbols are to be mapped in memory.

> Why there are no informations on the local variables' symbols

There may be three kinds of "local" variables in your program.

**main.c**

```
static int static_filescope_i = 1;

int f()
{
    static int static_local_i = 2;
    return static_local_i;
}

int g()
{
    int automatic_i = 3;
    return automatic_i;
}

int global_i = 4;

int main()
{
    return global_i + f() + g() + static_filescope_i;
}
```

An automatic variable like `automatic_local_i` is created on the stack at runtime
each time the program enters the block in which it is defined, and ceases to exist
then it leaves that block. Such a variable occupies no storage in the executable
so it is not represented in the symbol table.

A variable like `static_filescope_i` would often be called a *static global*,
to distinguish it from one like `static_local_i`. `static_local_i` cannot
be seen outside the block in which it is defined. `static_filescope_i` can
be seen in any function defined in the same object file (`main.o`) but
not in any other object file: it is *global* within `main.o` but
local *to that object file* within the program as a whole.

Both `static_filescope_i` and `static_local_i` must have its
initial value when the program first uses the variable and then keep
whatever value it has, or any new value assigned to it, until the next time
it is used - across function-calls, until the program ends. This means
that such variables need storage in the executable, not on the stack, and they *may or may not* be
represented in the symbol table.

`global_i`, of course, is global to the whole program: it can be seen in
`main.o` and any other other files we might link with `main.o`.

If we compile `main.c` with default options (no optimization):

```
$ gcc -c main.c
```

then we find:

```
$ readelf -s main.o | grep automatic_i
$
```

...no symbol for `automatic_i`.

```
$ readelf -s main.o | grep global_i
    12: 0000000000000004     4 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT    3 global_i
```

...a global symbol for `global_i`.

```
$ readelf -s main.o | grep static_filescope_i
     5: 0000000000000000     4 OBJECT  LOCAL  DEFAULT    3 static_filescope_i
```

...a local symbol for `static_filescope_i`

```
$ readelf -s main.o | grep static_local_i
     6: 0000000000000008     4 OBJECT  LOCAL  DEFAULT    3 static_local_i.1833
```

...and also a local symbol for `static_local_i`, but with a scope-distinguishing
suffix appended.

Here, `GLOBAL` means *can be seen by the linker*, and `LOCAL` means *cannot be seen
by the linker*.

So for the purpose of linking `main.o` with any other object files or libraries
to make an executable, `static_filescope_i` and `static_local_i` *might as well
not exist*.

That doesn't mean they are completely useless in the object file. They are useful
for debugging. They are useful for the purpose of investigating what the static
storage of the executable is made up of, as we are doing now.

But they're no use to the linker and so, if you compile `main.c` with any optimization
level > 0 then the compiler will assume you want object code that is not for
purposes of debugging or investigation and it will *not* emit any local symbols:

```
$ gcc -O1 -c main.c
$ readelf -s main.o | grep static_local_i
$ readelf -s main.o | grep static_filescope_i
$ readelf -s main.o | grep global_i
    11: 0000000000000000     4 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT    3 global_i
```

...only `global_i` remains.

That should explain why you're not seeing any of the "local" symbols. You r automatic
variables are never in the symbol table. Your static variables are only in the
symbol table if you have disabled all optimization.

Comment: Thanks Mike. It clarified my second question on the local variables. But my first question remains with few doubts. If i am building my code for a different machine how can my local linker get to know about the remote machines memory structure. Global variables address is printed same in both the macbines whereas the lo al variables address differs.  I noticed the global variablds' address is printed as a 6 digit but local variables' is 12 digit. Is that the global variables address is not the physical memory address of the RAM?